# Characteristic of ring $R_1\otimes\ldots\otimes R_k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R_1,\ldots, R_k$ be unital rings and $\otimes=\otimes_\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathrm{chr}$ the characteristic. How can one see that $$\mathrm{chr}(R_1\otimes\ldots\otimes R_k)=\gcd(\mathrm{chr}R_1,\ldots,\mathrm{chr}R_k)?$$

Edit: additionally assume that $\mathrm{chr}R_1,\ldots,\mathrm{chr}R_k$ are all nonzero.

Comment: This is my hunch, but I am not sure it is true. Does this also hold for $R$-algebras and $\otimes=\otimes_R$?

Comment: Did you try the case $k=2$?

Comment: There holds $\mathbb{Z}_m\otimes\mathbb{Z}_n\cong Z_{\gcd(m,n)}$, but I'm unsure about general rings.

Comment: However, this is false, in general: the tensor product of the rational field with a finite field is the zero ring.

Comment: What is $\gcd(0,n)$ again?

Comment: It's definitely not $1$, which is the characteristic of the zero ring: $\gcd(0,n)=n$.